# jQuery AutoComplete

Tags: jquery, plugins, autocomplete

I'm using the jQuery autocomplete plugin which works great,i have a small question, if a user begins typing in one field where the autocomplete is attached to, but then while the suggest is still showing they move to another input field which is also attached to autocomplete, the first input field does not show suggestions.

Are there any solutions to this, or is it pretty much the way works?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's a way you can have the suggestion completion event (I assume there is one) automatically re-display the suggestion of the other form.

Answer (score 0):

Your example also works if you move to another field which isn't an autocomplete field and I think this is how it's supposed to work. Compare it to a combo box. If you have its options pulled down and then tab to another field it closes the combo box.

If you never want the results to be hidden you could comment out the hideResults function call in the blur handler in jquery.autocomplete.js. However I'm assuming you'd want slightly more sophisticated behaviour so you may want to edit the function to suit your needs.